# Android custom class loading

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex

Has anyone have idea how to turn out 2 seperate dex files, where first one is for main project classes and another for libraries?
When i'm adding google+ libraries, i'm goint into "too much methods" in dex.

> Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

If anyone has similar problem, please share.
Thanks

Comment: not myself, but [Facebook had this problem](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920).

Comment: I may use the technics described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html but i'm stucked with library jars.

Comment: @guest: that's a different problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490382/#21492160 .