# DVM : methodIdx

Tags: android, dalvik

In the DVM source code you can see methodIdx used as Method ID in a lot of functions. This attribute isn't in the Method Class and I didin't find a good description about it.

So my question is, is an absolut identifier, it's allways the same for a process, can change, when can change, etc... And how or where is generated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`methodIdx` is generally the "method reference index".

It's an index into the `method_ids` table, described in the [file format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) docs.  The index is relative to a single DEX file, which is why functions like `dvmResolveMethod()` take the referring class as well as the method reference index.  It's mentioned in the `invoke-kind` explanation in the Dalvik [bytecode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html) doc.

Each `method_id_item` identifies a method by the class in which it was defined, and the function's prototype (name, arguments, return type).  There is one `method_id_item` for every method declared in or referenced from a DEX file.  The indices are established when the DEX file is generated by `dx`.

So... `methodIdx` gets you to a table entry with a bunch of strings.  From there a symbolic lookup gets you to the actual method implementation, i.e. `Method*`.  See `dvmResolveMethod()` in [dalvik/vm/oo/Resolve.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/oo/Resolve.cpp) for the details.

Because the `invoke` instructions only have room for a 16-bit method reference index, you can't refer to more than 65535 methods in a single DEX file.  (This is a [well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490382/does-the-android-art-runtime-have-the-same-method-limit-limitations-as-dalvik/21492160#21492160) problem.)

Comment: Thx! Nice answer. I can assume then that always with the same DEX each function has the same methodIdx, no? So for example I can use that number to identify the calls in a given dex file.

Comment: The pair { DEX file, methodIdx } resolves to a single specific method.  A single method should not have more than one method_ids table entry (as that would be a waste of space), so there should not be two different methodIdx values that resolve to the same method within a single DEX.  Note however that the same method, referenced from a different DEX file, could have a different methodIdx in the context of that DEX file.  And if your DEX file is updated then everything can change.

Comment: So it can't be used as identifier. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: It can be used as part of an identifier within a running VM process, or for a static set of DEX files, so long as you pair it with a reference to the DEX file that defines the method.  But no, the number alone isn't a globally-unique identifier.