# Error:Execution failed for task ':Click:dexDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

Please help me I have no idea what the problem could be. I just added the Google Play Service lib to my project. Maybe one of the libs are in duplicate as I searched for this error but how can I know which one?

I was thinking about the support library but now i should have only 1 from it in the project... (from the facebook project).

My build.gradle is this:

```
dependencies {
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.+@aar') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.+'
compile('com.google.guava:guava:+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('ch.acra:acra:4.5.+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('org.prx:playerhater:0.3.+') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile('com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar') {
    exclude(module: 'support-v4')
}
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.1'
```

And the error log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Click:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/hunyadym/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/20.0.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/acra-4.5.0-d67febab1bd096039e2714ead32d05ce94961100.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-query-full.0.25.10-b9bd0547bb11f071cd35aebb70a75373a66becf2.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/androidannotations-3.1-ae045caba46740aff968773eacbe72e2983b26cb.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/androidannotations-api-3.1-514701a967afaa48da10aefab6ae2f19aa761a6f.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/bolts-android-1.1.2-8f642fc35d1d9aca3ceb59e68edd672fa9b32e52.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-2c19c6a1d86006a8612f0b0abce112e3873a3831.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-379bacbe94579e3d2fde8fbcbc6294d0b2d9f059.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-6c2bc4223571c4c3b853887c2c5293e02b7e6e41.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-7f229ee6db4dce920a7e18935445adcbb5cd53b3.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-b55c3ef3198ae0cd7663e4548e8592e02f6644ae.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-cc12641f972062ce6e577b13b193a8da1e72e2ad.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-f160eda84b5660e2775ae684b2d52dbb36ad3743.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/codemodel-2.4.1-b32c33f43933b276a1c8ec5724e47f0763531f43.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/commons-io-2.4-a961edce1c87d4ce82efd4d400169f1a2917dea8.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/commons-lang3-3.1-eb9c0cfb1f644a5f642e79c0f661d23fea2ff903.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/dagger-1.2.1-f7b4fb82549fb11de67b640d6be8e79dd0ece7b8.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/gson-2.2.4-1c2432a53edefc5c5ed997ecf5c371769031f113.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/guava-18.0-7f45e9f8a9f6d41f727639dfa47b327c97aea17a.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11-3091f5fcbcf7761fd3b01697b281edd7534a1ce5.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11-4fa2150883feed9a06742b854791a6eea43d3bb1.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/javax.inject-1-48b0566163b971c7753db904d17b5910e8c8b43e.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jncryptor-0.3-6b1dadb43d6afe3ac3d372075b539a357d8da68a.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/joda-time-2.3-14db9682eba42b1c6b3696d7af4e01c972a31f42.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/libGoogleAnalyticsServices301-e4e18b568e4d4a7e738d7c3a18a4b62cbf6ff347.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/library-2.4.0-14f1436c4265d2edd5c91d8418b9d36b78b6d382.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/ormlite-android-4.48-bcf967de94a351eb097e5abe3fee2db674d95233.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/ormlite-core-4.48-ed093157f367c37ca04592a4948ed30a5b7c067d.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/picasso-2.3.4-8d657943f969eb5e3b11b7dc9f371e5cf97682cc.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/slf4j-android-1.5.8-dc595b91c33e55bcb0656a765e3896a31995fb23.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE-fcdedc6ba3126483f97975d38e0ea64ff05d9e1a.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE-5bee6f96887122c301c42cccdb556171352f853e.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1-ea7924ed3634c7274835ab69f369ee83bb198877.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-20.0.0-1406e278af41d116413a6a9d5303e0fe50da1f24.jar /Users/hunyadym/Android studioProjects/click_android/Click/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.1.0-90d8397ec29fd8b97f4f257abfc92caae23e2250.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many libraries and have exceeded [the 64K DEX method reference limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492160/115145). You can work to remove some dependencies and get back below this limit. For example, I do not know why you need two third-party JSON parsers (Jackson and GSON). Guava is also a "kitchen sink" library that may not be worth its weight.

Comment: i am using all of them :( are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: @MegaX: Yes, I am sure that `method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` is the symptom of the 64K DEX method reference limit.

Comment: yes i deleted guava, yodatime,jncryptor,commons-lang, and several others and now it's ok but if i add only one more lib then the same error occurs... then i can not put in any more lib in the future? oO

Comment: @MegaX: Google Play Services is also very large. You are welcome to configure your `build.gradle` to run ProGuard for debug builds, set to shrink only (and not obfuscate), to get rid of unused code, to see if that will help. There are also various recipes out there for pulling part of your app out into a separate DEX file, though I worry about security.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I am facing a very similar issue: I do not have that many dependencies but I suspect my error comes from libraries within my dependencies. Does that make sense? Some of those dependencies are transitive (like Twitter's Fabric SDK), so that's why I suspect that's the reason. Moreover, I thought of merging most of my dependencies on a library that would encapsulate them, but based on my theory, I don't think it'll work. What can I do?

Comment: @CristianGuerrero: "Does that make sense?" -- sure. It doesn't matter whether you require the dependency directly or indirectly. "What can I do?" -- switch to more granular dependencies where possible (e.g., the repackaged Play Services SDK). Use the new multidex stuff if needed.