# Conversion to dalvik format failed method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, dalvik

when am running my application i got this error.
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

and i have used only two libraries in my project those are play-services_library, facebook sdk

Comment: try cleaning the project and building it again

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833315/errorexecution-failed-for-task-clickdexdebug/25833358#25833358

Comment: i cleand  my project as many times and build it.