# Compilation Error : "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 74303 into a non-jumbo instruction"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, dalvik

I'm adding these two libraries in project `appcompat_v7 & google_play_services` but couldn't get the project compiled due to following Dalvik error

```
[2014-10-03 20:04:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 74303 into a non-jumbo instruction! 
[2014-10-03 20:04:57 - TestProject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 74303 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, Add `dex.force.jumbo=true` to project.properties.

See screenshot
[image]

Comment: Jumbo instructions were only supported for one release.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490382/does-the-android-art-runtime-have-the-same-method-limit-limitations-as-dalvik/21492160#21492160