# ART doesn't entirely replace Dalvik

Tags: android, dalvik

I keep reading articles about ART replacing Dalvik but, as far as I can determine, the ART Runtime is replacing the Dalvik Runtime, but that Dalvik bytecode (namely dex files) are still being used in ART. It looks as if, at the Dalvik bytecode level, nothing has changed. (There's no such thing as a specific ART bytecode.) Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490382/does-the-android-art-runtime-have-the-same-method-limit-limitations-as-dalvik

Answer (score 0):

Very True! However, with the new Jack/Jill Tool-chain the Dalvik byte code produced will most likely be refined, and re-engineered at the byte code level, and produce Dalvik byte-code that retains more information about the Java source code so that it can be more easily optimized by the back-end compilers in android's ART run time.