# What is the exact meaning of "Too many field references" in Android?

Tags: android, dex

I can check the classes.dex file through analyze apk in Android studio.

For example.

> This dex file defines 9214 clasees with 48592 methods, and references 57284 methods.

If the build fails because of a dex error, I will see the following error message.

> Too many field references: 70000; max is 65536.
>   You may try using --multi-dex option.

What exactly does 70000 mean in this error message?
Number of defined method? or Number of referenced Methods?

If the answer is a number of methods, is it possible to do the following result?

> This dex file defines 9214 clasees with 60000 methods, and references 70000 methods.

I've already read sentence below.

> The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536

(from [Document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=en))

But I don't know exactly what 65536 means.
Please tell me the answer. THX :)

Comment: You have to use MultiDex for your app where the methods count is greater than 64k.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I already know the multi dex option :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable multidex for your application.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Guide: [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

What exactly does 70000 mean in this error message?
Ans: Total methods count in your apk(includes methods count from libraries also).

Comment: Why do people mention "Number of referenced methods"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461328/what-is-the-difference-between-defined-methods-and-referenced-methods-in-android